# Several Properties of lim sup and lim inf in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

**Question:**

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ and $\mu: \mathcal{E} \to [0,\infty]$ a $\sigma$-additive function on $\mathcal{E}$. If I have an arbitrary sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{E}$, are the following statements true?

1. For $B \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$, $\mu(B) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$
2. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n^c = (\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n)^c$
3. $\mu(\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$
4. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n) \leq \mu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n)$

**My thoughts:**

1. here I would say that this is true, since $\sigma$-additive $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma$-subadditive
2. i tried the following: $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m)^c = (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m)^c = (\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n)^c$
3. Here i started like this, but got kinda stuck: $\mu(\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n) = \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m)$
4. I know this holds, provided $\mu(X) < \infty$, but does it also hold without this condition?

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As you already mentioned, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive, so $\mu(B)\leq\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n))\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$.
2. This seems to be correct.
3. This is wrong. Consider $X=[0,1],\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ and $\mu=\lambda\lvert_{[0,1]}$ (Lebesgue-measure). For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ put $A_n=[0,0.5]$ if $n$ is even and $A_n=[0.5,1]$ if $n$ is odd. Then $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{0.5\}$, so the LHS is $0$, but the RHS is $0.5$.
   However, as in this example, $\leq$ always holds: For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\mu(\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n)=\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m)\leq\mu(\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m)\leq\mu(A_n)$.
4. This generally doesn't hold if $\mu(X)=\infty$. Consider $X=\mathbb{R},\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mu=\lambda$. Put $a_1=0,b_1=1$ and for $n>1$ put $a_n=b_{n-1}, b_n=a_n+(b_{n-1}-a_{n-1})+1$. Now, put $A_n=[a_n,b_n]$. Then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\infty>0=\mu(\emptyset)=\mu(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)$.

Comment: So do i understand this right, that for $3.$ $\mu(A_n) = 0.5$, because $1-0.5 = 0.5-0$ is the measure of those $A_n$? And $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = 0.5$ because the limes inferior is defined as $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{k \geq n} A_k$ and we have as infimum $0$ and $0.5$ of those two intervals? And could you maybe briefly explain, why in $4.$ $\mu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n) = \mu(\emptyset)$?

Comment: @Eumel Regarding 3: Yes, all $A_n$ are intervals of length $0.5$, so their Lebesgue measure is 0.5. $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$ consists of all elements $x\in X$ for which there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $x\in A_n$. But since $A_n$ "flips back and forth", only the point 0.5 satisfies this condition. Regarding 4: $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,\infty[=\emptyset$ since $a_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me a lot :)